# Merge and Stack Multiple Sets of Columns dynamically - Power Query

Tags: excel, csv, merge, multiple-columns, powerquery

I have a single csv dataset that looks like below. I have multiple csv files like this which i want to combine once i figure out the correct transformation for a single file. Here is the [Sample Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vCyvvvjCltSE0jIwxfBRiqAUHv25Vt7z/view?usp=sharing) containing this data :
[image: Input csv table]

into this expected Output :
[image: Output table]

The Input data has broadly 4 sections :

1] The 1st 3 columns are used to create `Questions`, `Answers` & `Label` columns.

2] a section of Percentage columns.

3] a section of Stat-testing columns.

4] a section of 1 columns.

I want to `Merge` each set of columns `R.1....R10` and then `Unpivot` (`Stack`) them one above the other as shown in the output. The `R1...R10` column counts may vary each time, but they will be the same for each section i.e. for `Percentage columns`, `Stat testing columns` & `1 columns`.

While googling, i am came across an `Imke Feldmann` [post](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/06/19/unpivot-by-number-of-columns-and-rows-in-powerbi-and-powerquery-in-excel/) on Merging and unpivoting columns dynamically using a custom function. However, i am unable to select and merge the different sections of columns dynamically. Also, i found Bill Szysz's [post](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/the-world-of-bill-szysz/) which is somewhat similar and trying to figure out a way to modify his 2nd solution i.e. `Combine Method` on a similar post. Here is Bill Szysz's Combine Method solution.

```
let
    Source = Table.PromoteHeaders(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="UglyData"]}[Content], [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    Lists = Table.FromColumns({List.Transform({0..((List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source))-6)/5)-1}, each List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Source), _*5+6, 5)) }),
    AlmostReady = Table.Combine(Table.AddColumn(Lists, "Columns", each Table.FromColumns({Table.Column(Source, Table.ColumnNames(Source){0})} & {List.Repeat({[Column1]{0}}, Table.RowCount(Source))} & List.Transform(List.Skip([Column1], 1), each Table.Column(Source, _)), {Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}, "Name"} & List.Transform(List.Skip([Column1], 1), each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "_")) )   )[Columns]),
    Ready = Table.AddColumn(AlmostReady, "Total", each List.Sum(List.Skip(Record.ToList(_), 2)))
in
    Ready
```

The problem is, Bill uses fixed column and row counts ( 5 & 6) whereas my columns and rows count could change. for e.g. today there are 10 sets of columns per section, tomorrow there may be 5 or 20. But the columns count will always be the same across each section i.e. for Percentage section, Stats section and Number section. Also, the sequence of the Columns may change but maintain the same sequence across the sections:

e.g:

Percentage section   |     | Stats section             |     | Numbers section      |

R1 | R3 | R2 | R5 | R4 |     | R1 | R3 | R2 | R5 | R4 |     | R1 | R3 | R2 | R5 | R4 |

This data is tricky and beyond my amateur skills. Is this possible to do?

Comment: This is a messy problem that appears to require several different techniques to solve. If you can break it down into simpler subproblems and ask those separately, you may have better luck getting an answer as those will be easier to answer and more likely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: Yes, it is. That is why beyond my level of understanding. And this is just one csv file. Once i find the exact transformations for 1 csv, then I plan to convert it to a function and apply the transformations to other csv files imported together (to Combine them). Hope you are getting what i am trying to do.

Comment: But i think @horseyride has given below an elegant partial solution which had my brain racking for the past 1 week. The only thing is to somehow segregate the Questions, Answers & Labels as separate columns and then club the 3 tables together (First,Second,Third) to get the final output as shown in workbook.

Comment: Yep. That solves one piece of it. Then you'll need to do stuff like fill down column A, match that index up with Question and Answer number (via a subquery maybe?), add a tag column (Percentage/Stats/Numbers) to each First/Second/Third table, append them together, and sort.

Comment: Can you demonstrate with an example what you mean?

Comment: Not in a comment, no. I was just sketching some potential steps that would require a separate answer to write up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer, because I can't figure out what you are looking for in full

It creates three tables, each with the first three columns and then the following XX number of columns after that. You can combine and whatever with them as needed

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
List = Table.ColumnNames (Source),
Count = List.Count (List),
First = Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.FirstN(List,3)  & List.RemoveFirstN(List.RemoveLastN(List,(Count-3)/3*2),4)),
Second = Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.FirstN(List,3)  &  List.RemoveFirstN(List.RemoveLastN(List,(Count-3)/3),4+(Count-3)/3)),
Third = Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.FirstN(List,3)  &  List.RemoveFirstN(List,4+(Count-3)/3*2))
in Third
```

See if this works for you

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\SampleCSV.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
// get list and count of columns
List = Table.ColumnNames (#"Promoted Headers" ),
Count = List.Count (List),
// get list of columns from first table and preserve to rename in last step
FirstNames = List.RemoveFirstN(List.RemoveLastN(List,(Count-3)/3*2),4),
// divide the table into three tables by section and combine
Headers = List.Combine ({{"Que","Label","Agg"},FirstNames,{"Answer","Question"}}),
First = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers" ,List.FirstN(List,3)  & FirstNames)),1),
Second = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers" ,List.FirstN(List,3)  &  List.RemoveFirstN(List.RemoveLastN(List,(Count-3)/3),4+(Count-3)/3))),1),
Third = Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers" ,List.FirstN(List,3)  &  List.RemoveFirstN(List,4+(Count-3)/3*2))),1),
Combined = Table.Combine({First,Second,Third}),
// pull out the Question, Answer. Label, Que and fill down
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Combined, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Answer", each try if  #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Column1] <> "" and [Column1] = "" then [Column2] else null otherwise null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each try if [Column1]<> "" then [Column2] else null otherwise null),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom3", each try if #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Column1] <> "" or [Column3]="" then "kill" else null otherwise "kill"),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom2","",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Replaced Value",{"Answer", "Custom","Column1"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Custom3] = null)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index","Custom3"}),
// rename and reorder
#"Rename Columns" = Table.RenameColumns( #"Removed Columns", List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( #"Removed Columns" ),  Headers } )),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Rename Columns",List.Combine({{"Que", "Question", "Answer", "Label", "Agg"}, List.Sort(FirstNames)}))
in #"Reordered Columns"
```

Comment: This is interesting! How do i stack these lists to generate the final Output as shown in the workbook? I am an amateur in PQ.

Comment: That is very ingenious of you to first demote the headers and then skip the 1st row. I really like your clean and elegant approach. However, i did not understand this line, `Added Custom2 = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Question", each if [Answer] <> null or [Custom] <> null or [Column2] = null then "kill" else "ok")` where it is showing `Kill` for every row. The end result is, i am getting a fitered empty table.

Comment: Here is the same source file as a CSV to import. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WVe-kZPlErjHQhX1-gNMKx0yMAKbFhtb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Genius! This does it. The only thing is the sorting of the Labels, where the Percentages should be 1st row, Stat testing 2nd row, number 3rd row etc as seen in output. But this is definitely the answer. Thanks a bunch! :-)

Comment: add a custom column =1 =2 or =3 to the three tables before the merge, add the name to Headers,  then resort on that later.   Or first try reordering the combine of the three tables